# sql server query to display data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have data as:

```
id empid  amount   billamt
1   101   150.00   150.00
2   102   300.00   700.00 (sum(300+400))
3   102   400.00   700.00 (should be NULL)
--> i want this value to not repeat again,should be NULL
4   104   600.00   600.00 
5   105   200.00   600.00(sum(200+400))
6   105   400.00   600.00(should be NULL)
--> i want this value to not repeat again,should be NULL
```

As the empid's are same, so I want to show the sum value only once.

Comment: please post what you have tried .

Comment: Do you want to show last row with NULL or so not want to show duplicate row in later case refer Jens answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `Window function` to calculate total `amount` per `empid`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY empid ORDER BY id)        AS Rn,
                id, empid, amount,
                Sum(amount)OVER(partition BY empid) AS billamt
         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT id, empid, amount,
       CASE
         WHEN rn <> 1 THEN NULL
         ELSE billamt
       END billamt
FROM   cte
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13d2d/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can write as:

```
DECLARE @Emp TABLE (id INT,  empid INT, amount DECIMAL(10,2),billamt DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO @Emp VALUES      
(1,101,150.00,150.00),(2,102,300.00,700.00 ),(3,102,400.00,700.00 )

;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT id,empid,amount,billamt
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY Id ASC) AS Rownum
FROM @Emp) 
UPDATE CTE
SET billamt = NULL 
WHERE Rownum > 1

SELECT * from @Emp
```

Comment: You might want to explain that this will not only affect the select results but update the source table itself.